# JRE missing in Eclipse Mac

Tags: eclipse, java

When using Eclipse I get this error:

[image]

> ...re are no JREs installed in the workspace t...

Anyone knows what I have to do? Or which JRE (whatever this is) I need?
Just started this for school so I don't know a lot about Eclipse yet.

(First word is 'Build' in the error)

Edit:
Solved! New version of eclipse + JDK 7

Comment: Have you searched for the error? It's easier for others to help if you copy the error and paste it here (you can edit your question by pressing the gray edit-text below the tags). A picture may say more than words, but if all you're displaying are words anyway, why use the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [JDK 7 for Mac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html). Also please review notes.

After installation the JVM should be located in: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ path.
Java 6 is supported by Apple, so try to check path: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home. Suppose, concrete recipe to installation Java 6 on your Mac depends on your hardware and Mac OS version.

Comment: I reinstalled a new version of eclipse along with this and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JRE is the Java Runtime Environment. Do you have Java installed? It is not part of the OSX package any more.

Comment: It'd be difficult to run Eclipse without it.